# How to create a similar char pointer like char *argv

Tags: c, pointers, argv

The command line pointer char *argv [] used in C language allows operations such as;

```
ptintf ("%c", argv [3][6]); // to print the 7th element of 4th argument

printf ("%s", argv [3]); // to print the 4th parsed argument
```

Now I understand that argv char array is created before main function is called and it char *argv [] is merely a pointer directing towards that array created by the compiler.

How can we create a pointer in C code, which would allow similar operations?

I tried doing,

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char array [20] [20];
       char *ptr_array = array ;
      array [0] [0]= 'a';
      array [0][1]= 'b'; 
      array [0] [2] = '\0'; 

      array [1] [0]= 'a';
      array [1][1]= 'b'; 
      array [1] [2] = '\0'; 

      array [2] [0]= 'a';
      array [2][1]= 'b'; 
      array [2] [2] = '\0';          

 // assuming there is content in the array
    printf("%s\n", ptr_array [1]);
    return 0; }
```

but I end up with a warning  upon compilation and a core dump upon execution.

Comment: `ptr_array` is a pointer-to-char. I don't see what it's doing in your code. You want either a two-dimensional array (which you have, it's `array`), or a pointer-to-pointer (which in reality `argv` is). Just remove `ptr_array` from the code and use `array` instead. `printf("%s\n", array[1]);` should work fine. (Also, it seems you are confusing strings and individual characters – please read a basic tutorial on C strings and characters, and also read the man page for `printf()`.)

Comment: I will do as advised. regards. and appreciate your time.

Comment: But one question, Why do we use *argv inside the int main (int argc , char * argv)? If argc has all properties of an array I do not understand why we are using argv as a pointer array.

Comment: @deeplglicious What do you mean by "argc has all properties of an array"? It doesn't. It's just an `int`. Neither does `argv`, since it's not an array, it's a pointer-to-pointer. And we are using it like this because the language specification says so (it's the most practical way of getting command line arguments, since their length is unknown at compile time, so one can't really say that `argv` should be a pointer to array of known size.)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an array of pointers. So the declaration of `ptr_array` should be

```
char *ptr_array[20];    // an array of 20 pointer-to-char
```

The following code uses `strcpy` to fill in two of the strings in the `array`. The `{{0}}` makes sure that all the other strings are zeroed. Then the `ptr_array` is declared and all 20 pointers are initialized. Finally one of the strings is printed.

```
int main( void )
{
    char array[20][20] = {{0}};
    strcpy( array[0], "hello" );
    strcpy( array[1], "world" );

    char *ptr_array[20];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        ptr_array[i] = array[i];

    printf( "%s\n", ptr_array[0] );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there's no need for creating a separate array of pointers. Simply printing `array[i]` would work because `array[i]`, which is an array, decays into a pointer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant True, but the whole point of the question was how to create an array of pointers similar to the `argv` array that `main` has. So the `array[20][20]` is just the backing store that enables `ptr_array` without a bunch of `mallocs`.  The only thing that OP cares about is the `ptr_array`, because that's the *array-of-pointer-to-char* like `argv`.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want with simply `array`. No need for `ptr_array`.

```
char array[20][20];
// array initialization
printf("%s\n", array[1]);
printf("%c\n", array[1][1]);
```

---

`argv` is an array of char arrays. Exactly like `array` in the above code.

Command line arguments are passed as strings (`char` arrays) and `argv` is an array containing all those strings.

---

About use of `*` and `[]`:

```
char array[10];
```

`array` is now a pointer to the first element in that array, thus it is a `char*`.

For example, `char* argv[]` is the same as `char** argv`:

- `argv` is a pointer to the first element in the array containg `char*` elements, thus it is a `char**`.
- `argv[x]` accesses the `argv` array at index `x`, thus `argv[x]` is a `char*`, pointing to the first `char` in a string (a `char` array).
- `argv[x][y]` accesses the `char` array `argv[x]` at index `y`, thus `argv[x][y]` is a `char`, an element in a `char` array string.

Comment: this is a mere effort made to understand the application of argv. I do not understand why we use argv to be a pointer array. Why is it defined to be used as one? why couldnt we use it to be a notmal char argv instead of coding it to be a char *argv?

Comment: @deepIglicious if it were a 2-D array you'd have to specify a maximum length for each row which is unnecessarily restrictive and wastes a huge amount of memory

Comment: @deepIglicious Made an edit to clear that out. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: @deepIglicious Added some more explanation.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. You are conflating pointers and arrays continuously and repeatedly. "`argv` is an array of char arrays" – no, it's a pointer-to-pointer. That's different from an array-of-arrays. then: "`array` is now a pointer to the first element in that array, thus it is a `char*`" – no, it's an array of 10 characters, or a `char [10]`. It may *decay* into a pointer to its first element, but it's not a pointer by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array of pointers like

```
int main() {

       char *ptr_array[5] = { "ab","cd", "ef","gh" };     
       printf("%s\n", ptr_array [1]);
       return 0; 
    }
```

As you see argv was a array of pointers `char *argv []` you can come up with the same like shown above.

Note that the ptr_array here is just readable you can make it writable by allocating memory or making the pointers point to writable memory.

```
int main() {

       char *ptr_array[5]; 
       char str[20];
       int i=0;   
       for(i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
         ptr_array[i] = malloc(20);
         scanf("%s",str);
         strcpy(ptr_array[i],str);
       }
       printf("%s\n", ptr_array [1]);
       return 0; 
    }
```

PS: `argv` can be `*argv[]` or `**argv`

Comment: The strings pointed to by `argv` are writable so this does not quite achieve OP's requirements

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes yes .. I just showed what is *argv[] Will include your comment in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` has type `char[20][20]`.

In most contexts, using simply `array` converts it to a pointer to its first element: `&(array[0])` which has type `(*)char[20]` (pointer to array 20 of char).

You can assign this address to a pointer of the same type:

```
char array[20][20];
char (*ptr_array)[20]; // ptr_array is a pointer to an array of 20 char
ptr_array = array;     // types of ptr_array and (the converted) array are compatible
printf("%s\n", ptr_array[1]);
```